# PHP-Calculate Total Number of difference in years from table in Database

Tags: php, date

I would like to calculate the total number of difference in years. The scenario is as follows:
I have a table in a database. It contains details of members including their experience in years. I would like to get the total of experience years. For example The total years of experience of members is 90years.
So far i have tried and all i get is the experience of just a single member.

```
public function getMemberCollectiveExperience() {
        global $config;
        $db = new DatabaseController($config['db']['hostname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password'], $config['db']['database']);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_member WHERE status = 1";
        $result = $db->retrieveRecord($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                #get member years 
                $memberYears = $row['personal_experience'];
                $currentYear = date('Y');
                $firstResult = $currentYear - $memberYears;
                $total = $firstResult;
            }
            $result = array('count' => $total);
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: SO you get multiple records from query? @PhpDev

Comment: No idont. I only get the number of years of experience for just one member. I need to get the total number of years for all members @B.Desai

Comment: That's not what I am asking. By the way As I understand you have to store data in array:: $total[] = $firstResult;

Comment: my bad. i mis-interpreted you. no i dont get multiple records from query. I just tried your suggestion. It returns as "Array"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to get the total of all the differences

```
public function getMemberCollectiveExperience() {
        global $config;
        $total = 0;
        $db = new DatabaseController($config['db']['hostname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password'], $config['db']['database']);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_member WHERE status = 1";
        $result = $db->retrieveRecord($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                #get member years 
                $memberYears = $row['personal_experience'];
                $currentYear = date('Y');
                $firstResult = $currentYear - $memberYears;
                $total += $firstResult;
            }
            $result = array('count' => $total);
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, for some reason, i got an ambigious result. This was because i set the default personal experience for each member to 0. So during the loop, it kinda saw each of those zeros as the current year,2017 for some reason. I might be wrong though . So my response came out as 2108789. 
The following code fixed the problem

```
public function getMemberCollectiveExperience() {
        global $config;
        $total = 0;
        $db = new DatabaseController($config['db']['hostname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password'], $config['db']['database']);
        $sql = "SELECT personal_experience FROM tbl_member WHERE status = 1";
        $result = $db->retrieveRecord($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                if ($row['personal_experience'] != null && $row['personal_experience'] != 0) {
                    #get member years 
                    $memberYears = $row['personal_experience'];
                    $firstResult = date('Y') - $memberYears;
                    $total += $firstResult;
                }
            }
            $result = array('count' => $total);
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

thanks guys!